# Selection to cursor does not Center object origin in 3D cursor

Tags: transforms

I seem to be having an occasional but recurring problem when I try to snap an object to the 3D cursor.. Usually works but in some cases the origin misses the cursor.. I can repeat the command several times and sometimes it will find the cursor but sometimes not.

Comment: Hmm.. seems to be a specific problem, do you mind posting a gif or perhaps some pictures even so we could take a better look into the problem ?

Comment: While preparing screencast of this problem, I tried disabling Child Of constraint and sure enough Selection to Cursor worked...before posting this question I disabled Transform constraints which didn't help but never thought of disabling Child Of constraint..seems that this constraint somehow confuses the Selection to Cursor snap..thanks Retrax